# ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 70

Tags: node.js, ssl, nuxt.js

I'm developing with nuxt and trying to enable https env in local with using nginx as proxy. When I request with axios in nuxt, I got this error message

```
write EPROTO 4568841664:error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 70
```

The weird thing is, when I request with browser's address bar with protocol `https`, it works. Only request from node, this error message is shown. How can I solve it?

Comment: how does your axios request look like?

Comment: @Ifaruki hi! It looks like  {"url":"`https://mydomain`","method":"get","headers":{"common":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"delete":{},"get":{},"head":{},"post":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},"put":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},"patch":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},"Content-type":"application/json","X-ACCESS-TOKEN":""},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"withCredentials":true,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"body":{}}

Comment: I got a similar message when I tested a connection using openssl. While testing an endpoint doing a SSL handshake using TLSv1.0. You need to ensure you at least use TLSv1.1 or higher (TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3).